# Super collider drop downs instant search

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

When looking for other stack-exchange site, I usually use the Super collider drop downs menu search bar.

I would expect to be able to expand the menu and be able to type immediately the name of another site.

Could we automatically select the research field when the menu is clicked? Eventually, auto-scrolling to show the result would be great as well.

[image: SCDDM]

Edit: As stated by yo', the case of 7+ site in the menu should not be neglected. We do not want to scroll automatically if it masked the "favorite" sites. Maybe it could be triggered on key press only?

Comment: One problem is that for me, with 7 "my commnities", the dropdown is already almost too large, even without showing the field. So if you give focus to the field you either: **(1)** make the already large menu larger (bad), **(2)** give focus to an obstructed element (bad, moreover, browsers may scroll down automatically), **(3)** scroll down (bad). I dunno :-/

Comment: Maybe this could be triggered only when you type? I get your point and agree to it as well. Not sure what kind of interaction we can expect.

Comment: Anyways, I +1'd :) because I think the request is reasonable. But the problem I pointed out has to be addressed first.